# Selenium Java Internet Explorer Webdriver - Unable to find element

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, xpath, selenium-webdriver

It seems when I run the IE browser, it is unable to find the elements via xpath with error below:

> WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath:
>   //*[@id='signOnName'])
>       org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: session null does not exist (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)

I have enabled the Security settings via the code below:

```
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", prop.getProperty("IEDriverPath"));
            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
            caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true); //disable protected mode settings
            caps.setCapability("initialBrowserUrl", url);
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```

I found one saying that to fix it just add the remote server to the Trusted Sites `(Tools > Options > Security Tab > Trusted Site)`. However, due to work restrictions, I don't have admin access to go to the Options in IE. I can only do it via the automation script as per above.

Note that this is running fine in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: What is the IE version?

Comment: Details: **InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit) 3.8.0.0** _browserVersion=11_

Answer (score 0):

Try this, This might help:

```
DesiredCapabilities ieCapability = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
IEcaps .setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "BrowserAgent\\IEDriverServer.exe");
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapability);
driver.get("<<URL>>");
```

Thanks!

Comment: I tried using your code above. However, the issue became worse in the sense that it's not even picking up the URL and just stayed with the address http://localhost:35064/ with error: **This is the initial start page for the WebDriver server** ... May I know the reason why you suggested the above lines as it looks similar to what my code is except the sequence?